# Java arrayList variables

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, file-io

I am doing a homework assignment for my Java class. My instructor has some very defined requirements about what method calls and variables to use. One of the requirements is to write a method called public void initalizeSymbols(String inputFileName) that reads from an input file each letter of the alphabet and their morse code equivalent. I am trying to insure the variables are being passed to the arraylist, which we have to use, but can't get my System.out.println(input.toString()); to output anything which leads me to believe my variables arent being saved into the arrayList.  The arrayList will be storing a-z, 1-0, ? / and all of their equivalent Morse code symbols which are made up of ... and ---. So it will be storing both strings and integers. Any help would be appreciated. I apologize if this is not in the right format since it is the first time I've posted here.  Here is what I have:

```
public class MorseCodeTranslator
{
   private String sentence;
   private String translation;
   private ArrayList<MorseCodeSymbol> morseCodeSymbols;
   Scanner scannerIn;


 public void initializeSymbols(String inputFileName)                   
 {                                                                       
    String inputLine = "";                                              
    String letter = "";                                                 
    String symbol = "";


    try
    {
        scannerIn = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));                       
        while (scannerIn.hasNext())
        {

            inputLine = scannerIn.nextLine();

            letter = inputLine.substring(0, inputLine.indexOf(' '));
            symbol = inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf(' ') + 1);

            MorseCodeSymbol input = new MorseCodeSymbol(letter, symbol);
            morseCodeSymbols.add(input);

            System.out.println(input.toString());       //this doesnt work
            //System.out.println(letter + symbol);     //this works          


        }
        //MorseCodeSymbol input = new MorseCodeSymbol(" "," ");
        //morseCodeSymbols.add(input);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    //displayMorse();
}
}

public class MorseCodeSymbol 
{
    private String letter;
    private String symbol;

    public MorseCodeSymbol()
    {
        setLetter("");
        setSymbol("");
    }

    public MorseCodeSymbol(String letter, String symbol)
    {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public String getLetter()
    {
        return letter;
    }

    public String getSymbol()
    {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setLetter(String letter)
    {
       this.letter = letter;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol)
    {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("Letter: %s Symbol: %s", letter, symbol);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your file look like? Is `inputFileName` getting set? Why not start by `println`ing just `inputLine` and see what that outputs? Take some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), it's dangerous to go alone.

Comment: `System.out.println(input.toString()); //this doesn't work` Define "doesn't work". Prints nothing? Prints the wrong thing? Throws an exception?

Comment: By doesn't work, I was trying to say that the console outputs nothing.  When I use to local variables it will loop through and print the entire input file, so I know the input file is getting read.  Since the System.out.println(input.toString()) returns absolutely nothing, I am concerned the arrayList isnt storing the values form the input file.

Comment: What class is your snippit from? is it part of the `MorseCodeSymbol` class?

Comment: No it is in a class called MorseCodeTranslator.  These were predefined classes that the instructor had set up and we have to use, code cloned from him.  Inside MorseCodeTranslator, is the variable private ArrayList<MorseCodeSymbol> morseCodeSymbols; which we have to use.

Comment: When you try to print `input.toString()`, you are trying to call the method `MorseCodeSymbol.toString()`, which is (presumably) defined inside the MorseCodeSymbol class. You have added the custom `toString()` method which you appear to want to call, to your `MorseCodeTranslator` class instead. Look inside the MorseCodeSymbol class to see what its `toString()` method is doing.

Comment: I apologize, my toString() method is actually in MorseCodeSymbol class with my constructors, getters and setters.  I had just added it on here to show how the toString was written. I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: Please include source for your `MorseCodeSymbol` class if possible, rather than tacking bits of it onto the end of another class, then.

Comment: No problem, just did.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I needed to initialize the arrayList under the method initialzeSymbols. I knew it was something super simple I was overlooking